# mysql@5.7 installed via homebrew- Bootstrap failed: 37: Operation already in progress

Tags: mysql, homebrew

```
macOS v12.5.7
Homebrew 3.6.10
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 1e446908eb9; last commit 2022-11-12)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision d9344bd366; last commit 2022-11-12)
```

I need to install an older version of MySQL (v5.7) because that's the version my employer is stuck on at the moment.  My goal is to be able to run `mysql -uroot` and have a mysql terminal open up.

I have a clean install via `homebrew`:

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.39, for osx10.17 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

$ type -p mysql
mysql is /usr/local/bin/mysql
```

I run `brew link mysql` because I know this older version is keg-only, and I want to be able to run a MySQL executable from my terminal:

```
$ brew link mysql@5.7
```

When I run `brew services start mysql`, I get:

```
$ brew services start mysql      
Error: Formula `mysql` is not installed.
```

OK, so I try `brew services start mysql@5.7`:

```
$ brew services start mysql@5.7
Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error
Try re-running the command as root for richer errors.
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/502 /Users/richiethomas/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql@5.7.plist` exited with 5.
```

This error is a bit inscrutable.  I know if I were to run this in `sudo`, I'd get more verbose output, so I try that:

```
$ sudo brew services start mysql@5.7
Warning: Taking root:admin ownership of some mysql@5.7 paths:
  /usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.7/5.7.39/bin
  /usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.7/5.7.39/bin/mysqld_safe
  /usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7
  /usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin
  /usr/local/var/homebrew/linked/mysql@5.7
This will require manual removal of these paths using `sudo rm` on
brew upgrade/reinstall/uninstall.
Warning: mysql@5.7 must be run as non-root to start at user login!
/Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.mysql@5.7.plist: service already bootstrapped
Bootstrap failed: 37: Operation already in progress
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap system /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.mysql@5.7.plist` exited with 37.
```

Looks like the key line in this error is `Bootstrap failed: 37: Operation already in progress`.  I tried Googling around a bit for this error, but got no relevant results.

For reference, here's the output of `brew services list`:

```
$ brew services list                
Name          Status  User         File
memcached     started richiethomas ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.memcached.plist
mysql@5.7     stopped root         ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql@5.7.plist
nginx         started richiethomas ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist
openvpn       none                 
postgresql@13 started richiethomas ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@13.plist
redis         started richiethomas ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.redis.plist
unbound       none
```

Any ideas on how to get unblocked and reach my goal of launching the `mysql` terminal?